# what is a string not visible but not " " ? ajax php mysql

Tags: javascript, ajax, request

i am programming a chat and for this i send a ajax request to a php file and get echoed werner as msg. But its not only werner as a string because msg.length shows 13 character. 
I thought it might be empty string but its not because

```
if(msg[i]==" ")
```

is not true and

```
msg[i]==""
```

isn't true either but `typeof(msg[i])` shows its indeed a string.

So what can it be?

The reason i need to know because i want to ask `if(werner==msg)` but it delivers false because `msg` has some empty string in it and has 13 characters and not 6

this is what my js code looks like:

```
   $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ausmisten.php",
                success:function(msg){

                 alert(msg);//shows werner
                 alert(typeof(msg));//String
                 alert(msg.length);//13
                if(msg=="werner")//not true
                $("#Abmelden").click();//not executed

            }


        });
```

the php file

```
echoes "werner"
```

the important part from the php file is:

```
$result=mysqli_query($db,"select distinct name from Datenbank1");
$array=mysqli_fetch_array($result);
echo $array[0];//$array[0]="werner"
```

i changed my problem to ausmisten.php empty php file

and TEST.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<title>
Versuch
</title>
</head>
<body>
<div id="ausgabe"></div>//8string is shown
</body>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script>
 $.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"ausmisten.php",
    success:function(msg){
        $("#ausgabe").html(msg+msg.length+typeof(msg));

        }

});
</script>



</html>
```

the output in webbrowser when TEST.html is:

```
8string
```

Comment: Can you show some code please?

Comment: Try `var_dump($msg);` (Assuming "werner" is inside $msg) to see exactly what it contains.

Comment: Are you sure this is a PHP question? `typeof` is a JS thing

Comment: thanks but its javascript and not php

Comment: but i get it echoed from a php file

Comment: but i wrote ajax in the question title

Comment: So echo the var_dump. The javascript doesn't matter unless your PHP file simply does `echo "werner";` In that case the problem is somewhere else.

Comment: On a side note: You probebly don't want to create a chat based on Ajax (long polling) anyway. As soon as you have about 10 / 15 ppl in your chat, your server is NOT going to like it. Websockets would be a far better choice imho :)

Comment: var_dump shows werner as string and 6 characters which is what you expect but get it via callback ajax function in javascript where it isnt only "werner" anymore

Comment: so the php file does simply echo "werner"

Comment: In that case we can't help you unless you show us your code. There can be any number of reasons for this to happen. We'd be guessing here all night long. So please edit your question and paste any relevant code

Comment: $.ajax({
                type:"POST",
                url:"ausmisten.php",
                success:function(msg){








                     alert(typeof(msg));//String
                     alert(msg.length);//13
                    if(msg=="werner")//not true
                    $("#Abmelden").click();//not executed
                    
                }
                
                
            });

Comment: Please add your PHP code as well. No need to comment it. Just edit your question only.

Comment: I'm not seeing any problems with that code. Something else somewhere in your code must be causing the problem.

Comment: i cant see the problem either

Comment: even if i write echo "werner"; its not working

Comment: Well, you're not going to like what I'm about to say, but none of us here can help you solve a problem that we can't see. We most likely would need to see the entire code and your database contents to figure out what exactly is going on. And that's just to much information to put in a question here.

Comment: i changed the ausmisten.php to echo "werner"; solely

Comment: it is sending msg.length equal 8 when the php file is empty

Comment: Try alerting msg.length.trim(). if its length is 6 instead of 13, there are spaces in the `werner` string.

Answer (score -1):

Even a empty site sends a few empty strings you have to cut  out the empty strings